# can't remove the field with remove function

Tags: jquery, html

This image shows the scenario

[image: addMoreAndRemove]

When my page load and I go for inserting data these four will be shown by default. When I click at `+ button` the last row append, now when I click at `x button` its shows the current id after appended the row but when I want to remove it it doesn't remove the row.

and my javascript code is

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[name=forLess]', function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
        alert(currentId);
        //$("#addMoreCounter_" + currentId).remove();
    });
```

and if current text fields have something written in it also should be empty the current text field.

Comment: Need to see HTML and the javascript for the "X" and "+" buttons.

Comment: I remove all my previous code that was useless.

Comment: please see the how-to-ask page. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated my answer with my new code.

Comment: Did anyone see my updated answer.

Comment: I wanted to help you but I couldn't understand what you are trying to achiev, sorry.

Comment: `cr0ss` can you see the last row which have four text field when I click at `+` button one row should be added at last only with `x`.

Comment: Replicate your problem in a fiddle...

Comment: thats what I'm doing.

Comment: can you save fiddle program? I can't save the fiddle program when I click at save button

Comment: `ArinCool` can save program on fiddle because I can't save the program at fiddle.

Comment: Please some one tell me jsfiddle is not working? I can't save my program.

Comment: Setup jsfiddle / share your code on how you're adding new row.

Comment: Your updated question still doesn't include: the code that creates the new rows; an example of the HTML created for those rows (so we have some idea whether `#addMoreCounter123` is a row, a cell, etc.; the code or at least the attribute values for the "x" buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of HTML, let's make some assumptions :

- the rows are tr elements in a table
- the [+] buttons have `class="add"`
- the [x] buttons have `class="remove"`

You could do something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#myTable").on('setButtonState', function () { //Attach a custom event handler on the table, for setting the state of its remove buttons.
        var $remove = $(this).find('.remove');
        $remove.prop('disabled', $remove.length <= 4); //Disable the [x] buttons if there are 4 or less, otherwise enable them.
    }).on('click', '.add', function() { //Delegate click handling of the [+] buttons' to the table.
        // ... your append() code here ...
        $this.closest('table').trigger('setButtonState');
    }).on('click', '.remove', function() { //Delegate click handling of the [x] buttons' to the table.
        $this.closest('tr').remove().closest('table').trigger('setButtonState');
    }).trigger('setButtonState'); //Set the initial state of the [x] buttons (on page load)
});
```

Please note: If the top row is to be deletable, then you will need to put the [+] button somewhere else, or you'll lose it!